# Regular expression sequence matching

Tags: regex

Is it possible to create a regular expression to find an incrementing sequence of hex numbers?  I am trying to find number sequences (4 numbers long) inside seemingly random hex number strings.

`... 59 fd 25 bf b1 b2 b3 b4 39 ca ...`
`... 35 c1 55 c4 c5 c6 c7 74 92 e1 ...`

I was hoping to find the pattern `b1 b2 b3 b4` in line 1 and `c4 c5 c6 c7` in line 2.

Group matching will find *same* number sequences... `/(\w\w)\1{3}/` will find `c4 c4 c4 c4` but I haven't found a way to match the incrementing sequence.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`Regex` is used for matching patterns occurring repeatedly **not** for matching patterns occurring incrementally

You better parse it with your own parser